# How to call bean method from javascript

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, primefaces

I have a xhtml page where I have implemented tabView using Primefaces.

```html
<p:tabView id="editorTab" styleClass="mySubPanelStyleNew"
  dynamic="true" cache="false"
  activeIndex="#{certInquiry.defaultIndex}" onTabChange="savetab()"
  effectDuration="0" tabChangeListener="#{certInquiry.onTabChange}"../>
```

From tabView I call a Javascript function. I want to call my Backing bean method from this javascript function.

The savetab() in above code is defined in my .js file.

```js
function saveTab() {
 removeSpellcheckwindow();
 var b = jQuery("#certEditorForm1\\:changeTag").val();
 var a = jQuery("#certEditorForm1\\:wordchangeTag").val();
 if (b == "true" || a == "true") {
  
  jQuery("#certDetailsEditorForm\\:certDetailSubmit").click();
  jQuery("#certEditorForm3\\:dummySave").click()
 }
}
```

In my saveTab() before the condition "if (b == "true" || a == "true")", I want to call a method in one of my Handler classes and then resume with my if condition.

I tried the following approach but failed to attain my functionality.
I created a hidden  in my xhtml file, and called the bean method as a listener. Then in my saveTab() I created a jquery to click my hidden commandButton. It works but the basic problem is that while the bean method executes my saveTab() keeps executing and doesn't wait for my bean method to complete.

Could anyone suggest an approach to my problem.

Comment: I'd normally start by using google, checking out the PF showcase and documentation. Something about a remoteCommand

Comment: My issue is how to call it before my "onTabChange" of tabView gets executed.

Comment: Then use the onstart attribute of the ajax onTabChange event

Comment: can you please quote an example

Comment: Code in a comment looks aweful and it will not be an answer. Why don't you start yourself and have us comment on it. There were 3 suggestions in my first comment. Did you try either of them?

Comment: with the remote command option, my tab changing feature isn't working. Secondly, for <p:ajax> i am in a dilemma how to call the ajax and then again send the control back to <p:tabView>

Comment: I thought so. OnTabChange as a attribute on the tabview tag  has been removed many versions ago. I think it is next to impossible to achieve what you want. So you also use jsf 1.2?

Comment: sorry, but I don't have the jsf version as of now as I my project is in  office sytem. Is the version important to you to provide a solution?

Comment: I can't provide a sution since I do not know how to fix this in PF 2.2. Jsf version is indeed less important then

Comment: ok. If you find any other solution, please post it.

Answer (score 0):

> ".. the basic problem is that while the bean method executes my saveTab() keeps executing and doesn't wait for my bean method to complete."

In general you could try something like this:

```
<p:remoteCommand name="rc" actionListener="#{bean.method()}"
         oncomplete="saveTabPartTwo(xhr, status, args)" />

function saveTabPartOne(){
    //before bean method is called
   rc();
}
function saveTabPartTwo(xhr, status, args){
    // after bean method finished
}
```

> "In my saveTab() before the condition "if (b == "true" || a == "true")", I want to call a method in one of my Handler classes and then resume with my if condition."

To do this, you need to carry your variables from saveTabPartOne() to the remote command and then to saveTabPartTwo().

Comment: the problem here is after calling remoteCommand the control wont go back to tabView. I am unable to change tabs after adding remotecommand.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the issue correctly. Do you mean you can't change tabs by clicking or do you want to switch tabs programmatically?

Comment: I am not able to change tabs by clicking